# remote connection to postgresql in cpanel

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, cpanel

I have a spring boot application, i tried to connect It to a remote database (postgresql) created in a cpanel server but i got this error: An error occurred while setting up the GSS Encoded connection, to fix It i added gssEncMode=disable, then i got this error : Une erreur s'est produite pendant l'établissement de la connexion SSL. here is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db?gssEncMode=disable
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=9080
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500KB
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

Please help me to fix this issue!! Question:how can I get the host and the port of my cpanel server? how can i configure my postgresql database to receive connections from a spring boot application?what are the steps to connect a spring boot application to a postgresql database created in cpanel ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter also to jdbc url then retry :

```
sslmode=require
```